# character encoding differences between local, Dev, and Prod env causing a roadblock

Tags: php, python, apache, vim, character-encoding

I have one file filled with Apache redirect rules that was sent to both a development server and production server, which were manually setup roughly the same. Using Vim, the text of the file is displayed as it is intended to be read both locally and on the dev server (with all the irregular characters) but once uploaded to the production server, vim there understands none of the irregular characters and Apache cannot match the urls containing them to the actual site urls.

I programmatically created this Apache redirects file from scrapes of old and new sites using a python script with '#coding: utf8' set.

In the URLs are story titles that were generated by Drupal and they consist of French, Spanish and English titles. the English have plenty of apostrophes (') and the French and Spanish have many more irregular characters.

How can I get my production server to behave like my development server and local machine - encoding the text correctly (system-wide I suppose)?

Comment: What's the locale setting on the misbehaving server?

Comment: oh, hello there problem...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX

Comment: that was for $ locale -a
$ locale adds
LANG=en_PH.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_PH.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_PH.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_PH.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

Comment: I'm just reading as I go here...
I have no /etc/default/locale file
there is an /etc/locale.alias file, although that file says it is obsolete.
/var/lib/locales/ is empty other than supported.d which is also empty.

Comment: I performed:

sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8

dpkg-reconfigure locales 

and added:

LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

LANG=en_US.UTF-8

to /etc/default/locale

/var/lib/locales/supported.d/ now contains local with the same contents

Yet, still:

locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory

locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory

locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory

C

C.UTF-8

POSIX

en_US

en_US.iso88591

en_US.utf8

Comment: and finally, "apt-get install language-pack-en-base" + dpkg-reconfigure locales worked

Comment: You can answer your own question to close this as you have found the solution.

Comment: yeah, I tried but it wouldn't let me answer for 8 hours or something... and then I got busy with the next thing. Anyway, thanks for jumping in with the question to put me on the right track. and thanks to SO for keeping the answer I typed but wasn't allowed to post right away so I didn't need to redo it. That was a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base
dpkg-reconfigure locale
```

I had tried:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

followed by adding:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

to /etc/environment/locale, and while that did populate /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local with the same, it did not work.
the final fix was sourced from:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue